# Merge and reverse

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a problem with git. I'm pretty new to git. Me and my team are working on the project and I accidentally merged branches. After I merged other team member pushed and after that I pulled. After I pulled, my code stopped working. It doesn’t matter what I write, it just doesn’t underline the line. Any solutions?

Comment: Are you able to see the history of your commits typing `git log`?

Comment: `pull` just means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, usually `git merge`* so if you did a merge after a fetch, you did a pull, and/or vice versa. I think the biggest problem with your question as posted here is that none of us can see your repository itself, nor the actual commands you ran. (And I don't know what you mean by "underline the line", but images of problems are discouraged unless that's the only way to show them.)

Answer (score 1):

You should identify the commit in which everything was working and `checkout` the directory to that commit. You can also create a new branch from that commit.

Another option is to use sourcetree to identify the differences between two commits to find what is wrong after you last pull.

Nobody can give you the right solution, you should inspect the history and find what went wrong.
Anyway if you commit push and pull regularly everything is stored and the working solution is preserved....it only a matter of find it :-)

Comment: I think what happened is I was out of town and didn’t have my laptop and at that time everyone was pushing and when I finally got home I was so behind that it didn’t let me pull so I had to merge

Comment: That is quite normal, git is able to manage this situation. The fact that you need to merge during the pool means that you had local changes that were not pushed.

Comment: I see what you mean. So do I try to checkout the directory to the state when it was working?

Comment: yes, extacly...go back in the history until you are in a stable situation

Comment: Okay. Thank you so my